# Updating NuGet reference in a different repo in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have set up a multi-repo in Azure DevOps using Git. Assume I have 2 repos (Repo A and B) for simplicity.

Repo A's outcome is a common library DLL. Repo B references Repo A's generated DLL (via a NuGet package).

The CD pipeline of Repo A pushes the NuGet package (which was packed during the CI pipeline of Repo A) to my Azure Artifacts feed.

Is there a way to add a task in the CD pipeline of Repo A to automatically change the NuGet package reference (to a newer version) in the project of Repo B? This way, when Repo B gets pulled on the local repository, the reference would be updated instead of going through the NuGet Package Manager and updating manually in Visual Studio?

**Update:**

After applying your suggestions, everything is working perfectly except the fact that when I pull the changes of RepoB to my local repo, the new NuGet package of Repo A is not available in the packages folder [of Repo B] and I have to manually get it from the Package Manager.

Pre-Build event helps here but I want Repo B be fully up-to-date upon pulling from Azure Repos.

Below is the CD pipeline of Repo A.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to add a task in the CD pipeline of Repo A to automatically change the NuGet package reference (to a newer version) in the project of Repo B?

There is no such out-of-the-box approach to doing this.

The simple way is:

Add a Pre-build event to the project in the Repo B with following command line:

```
nuget.exe update $(ProjectDir)packages.config
```

In case, when Repo B gets pulled on the local repository, the reference would be updated when you build the project in the repo B. But the limitation for this way is that this method will only modify our local files and will not directly modify the files in the repo. We still need to submit the changes to the repo manually.

The Complex way is:

Add a command line task in the CD pipeline of Repo A to use git command line to clone repo B:

```
git config --global user.email "xxx@xyz.com"
git config --global user.name "Admin"

git clone <repo> <directory>
```

Then add powershell or any other task to update the `Reference`, `HintPath` info in the project file and the package version in the `packages.config` file.

After modifying the files, add another command line task to submit the changes to the repo:

```
git commit -m "Update package version"

git push -u origin master
```

**Update:**

When you use `git clone <repo> <directory>` to clone the repo, you need to provide your certificate in your source link, usually using PAT:

[image]

The link looks like:

```
https://<OrganizationName>@dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/MyTestProject/_git/TestSample
```

Then we need to replace the first `OrganizationName` with PAT. So, it will be:

```
https://<PAT>@dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/MyTestProject/_git/TestSample
```

For your case, it should be:

```
https://<PAT>@xxxxx.Visualstudio.com/....
```

Then I could clone it successfully.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the simple way works seamlessly, thanks! Currently trying the complex way, however facing some issues. While cloning, should I use `git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer $(System.AccessToken)"`? Moreover, better to use Project References or packages.config?

Comment: @naregkar, If the simple way works for you. You can use this way, it is recommended. The complex way need to use scripts to modify the file in the repo, it is not the recommended and unsafe. For the Project References or packages.config, it depens on the project type you are using, SDK type using `Project References`, non-SDK type, using `packages.config`.

Comment: I had hoped and prefer the complex way as it automatically updates the project references. I don't mind using scripts. This is the command line [link](https://imgur.com/QsvayaX) to clone and I get this error: `##[error]Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt`. That is why I asked if I should use the extraheader. Thanks!

Comment: @naregkar, Sorry for reply later, I have updated my answer with some more detailed info, please check if it helps you.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed explanation. Yesterday, I already found a way with the above mentioned bearer token. There is an error although it is cloning successfully. The strange behavior is that if I use Azure hosted windows-2019 agent, I don't get this error.; only on a local agent it appears. Maybe this is a bug?

Comment: Your answer helped me so much except one remaining step which I added in my original post. Thanks again :)

Comment: @naregkar, no problem. I will check your update and check if I can resolve it later.

Comment: @naregkar, when you pull the changes of RepoB to your local repo, **have you check if the version of Repo A changed to the new version?** If yes, then,  if the new NuGet package of Repo A is not available in the packages folder [of Repo B] **after you build your RepoB**?

Comment: When I pull the changes of Repo B, version number in `packages.config` and `Reference`, `HintPath` of Project B are all updated. When I build project B, the newer package of Repo A gets downloaded into the packages folder. I'm not sure if there is a way **without building**, it updates the references. _Maybe I should put the packages folder inside Azure Repos and not ignore it? This is a hassle and usage of extra bandwidth though._

Comment: @naregkar, No, you do not need to put the packages folder inside Azure Repos. What I need to emphasize is that you have already updated the references. The package version in the `\packages` folder updated by nuget restore. This is an expected operation. Otherwise, you need put the packages folder inside Azure Repos, it is not recommend.

Comment: So this means this is the max we may reach to, a build is necessary in order for the package to be restored locally, no?

Comment: @naregkar, Yes, as you know, the `\package` folder is ignored by the source control, it is not exists in the repos. So, we could not operate packages in that folder before we restore them.

Comment: Very well! Thanks a lot. All solved except the Git error I mentioned earlier. I open a new thread for that.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done a bit differently than asked.

**Using Project References** (Newer projects):

Change your Repo B project's package reference version to get the latest using the wilcard symbol `*` in the `Version` attribute.

```
<PackageReference Include="MyPackageName" Version="*" />
```

**Using packages.config**

`packages.config` does not support the wildcard symbol and takes a few more steps.

You will need to add the following to your `nuget.config` file inside the `<configuration>` section:

```
<config>
    <add key="dependencyversion" value="Highest" />
</config>
```

Be sure that the nuget.config is a part of the repo.

Then In the pipeline's `Nuget restore` task under the `Feeds to use` section select `Feed in my NuGet.config` and then specify the path to the repo's nuget.config.

In either case, when Repo B compiles in the pipeline it will grab the latest.  When the repo is pulled down clean or for the first time it will grab the latest on the initial compile as well and on any new version that has been published.

Comment: I tried this, however it is not automatically downloading the newer package. Trying Leo Liu-MSFT suggestion. Thanks!