# Global TDS config change

Tags: xml, azure-devops, sitecore, config, tds

We have a Sitecore based C# project setup in Azure DevOps. In the project there is a TdsGlobal.config file that date how far back to get the TDS changes. This should be dynamically changed during the deployment only to get the previous 3 weeks of TDS packages.

```
<IncludeItemsChangedAfter>2019-04-01</IncludeItemsChangedAfter>
```

The above field in TdsGlobal.Config needs to be changed after each Production deployment. Any suggestions how to achieve to this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Global TDS config change

If you **only** update `IncludeItemsChangedAfter` field in `TdsGlobal.Config` during the Production deployment instead of updating this field in the **repo**, you could use the task [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) to update the key's values:

```
<IncludeItemsChangedAfter>#{TDSChangesDate}#</IncludeItemsChangedAfter>
```

If you need to update the change in the repo, there are two ways to achieve this.

One is using the REST API [Pushes - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#update-a-file) to update the `TdsGlobal.Config` file:

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59304119/azure-devops-pipeline-task-to-update-a-file-and-check-in-tfs) for some more detailed steps.

Another is use powershell scripts to update the file and git command line to submit the the change into the repo:

- Add a command line task clone the repo.

  ```
  git config --global user.email "xxx@xyz.com"
  git config --global user.name "Admin"

  git clone <repo> <directory>  //The repo should be https://<PAT>@dev.azure.com/<OrganizationName>/xxxxx/_git/xxx
  ```
- Add powershell or any other task to update the file `TdsGlobal.Config`.
- Add another command line task to submit the changes to the repo:

  ```
  git commit -m "Update package date"

  git push -u origin master
  ```

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57728238/updating-nuget-reference-in-a-different-repo-in-azure-devops/57755016#57755016) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. Due to the number of potential build per release we need to figure out a way to up the date only ONCE the build has been deployed all the way up to Production.

In post Production deployment we will always need to merge the Release branch back to Master and then one final merge back to Develop, so its at that point, I think we should up the date. Any suggestion on how to track this scenario.

Comment: @ChamodhHettiarachchi, So, it seems you should update the file in the repo. You could consider the second case. To track this scenario, you could create a pipeline to update the file, then add a branch policies with Build validation that you created before. In this case, only you  merge the Release branch back to Master, it will update the date in the repo.