# Bash script successfully executes locally but not in Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: bash, azure-devops

I have a bash script that executes successfully in my local environment:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#build changelog

version="Version: "
current_date=`date`
cat <(printf " \n") <(echo $version $env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER $current_date) <(tail -n+6 pr-changelog.md) ./CHANGELOG.md > output 
mv output ./CHANGELOG.md
```

However using the the Bash build package in my Azure Devops pipeline, whilst the script succeeds, does not throw any errors and the pipeline completes, the changes in the script do not take place.

The script copies lines from one file to the `CHANGELOG.md` and a couple of other small things. Locally the text is copied, but after running the pipeline, the `CHANGELOG.md` file has not changed in my branch.

Can I expect this to work and if not, what further steps should I take?

TIA

Comment: Note that you don't need the `cat` + process substitutions. Just create a block with a redirection: `{ printf '%s\n' ' ' "$version $env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER $current_date"; tail -n+6 pr-changelog.md; cat ./CHANGELOG.md; } >output`. Doing that will make your code `sh` compatible, for if the `#!/bin/bash` shebang is somehow being ignored (something running `sh yourscript` would do that, for example; and process substitutions aren't valid POSIX sh syntax, so the script isn't guaranteed to work with a baseline-POSIX interpreter, which is all `sh` is guaranteed to provide).

Comment: BTW, when you say "changed in my branch", do you expect the change to be propagated back to the source control repository, or are you referring only to the file being updated in build outputs? (I don't know Azure Devops enough to answer this myself, but the distinction is an important one to make clear).

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy - I will those changes to the script - yes, I am expecting the changes to take place in the branch the pipeline is running on, but maybe that expectation is wrong - the particular pipeline I'm using doesn't publish a build or any artefacts.

Comment: _nod_. Most CI systems I've worked with don't do that (committing and pushing working-tree changes back to the repo) unless someone goes out of their way to write code for the purpose; but again, I haven't worked with this particular one so I can't speak to it definitively.

Comment: Ok understood - I'm going to try and figure out how to approach this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Bash script successfully executes locally but not in Azure Devops pipeline

When we execute the build on the Azure pipeline, it will checkout the source from the repo to the build agent and the next operation is also done on the agent. It will not directly affect the repo, this way will protect the security of the source in our repo.

That is the reason why the changes in the script do not take place in your branch.

To resolve this issue, we need to submit this change to the repo by the git command: `git add` `git commit` and `git push`:

```
git config --global user.email "xxx@xyz.com"
git config --global user.name "Admin"

cd "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"

version="Version: "
current_date=`date`
cat <(printf " \n") <(echo $version $env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER $current_date) <(tail -n+6 pr-changelog.md) ./CHANGELOG.md > output 
mv output ./CHANGELOG.md

git add CHANGELOG.md

git commit -m "copies lines to CHANGELOG.md"

git push https://<PAT>@dev.azure.com/YourOrganization/YourProject/_git/YourProject HEAD:master
```

I test it with Azure pipeline, it works fine.

Comment: Thanks very much @Leo Liu-MSFT! I will try this out - One question - can I checkout another branch (not the one that will be merged to / master / that the pipeline is using) and commit on that branch? So for example - I make a PR, it gets merged which triggers the pipeline, and during pipeline execution the above script checks out another branch (called let's say 'changelogs') in the same repo and makes a commit there?

Comment: @Mr.Robot, I did not test it, but I think it is possible. We can create a new folder and use the git clone command to clone the specified branch: `git clone -b <branch> <remote_repo>`, you could check my similar thread about this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57728238/updating-nuget-reference-in-a-different-repo-in-azure-devops/57755016#57755016

Comment: Ok thank you - I will read this in detail - but my thought is could I not just reference another branch (say 'changelogs`) in the same repo here `cd "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"`? As I do not need to push to another repo, just another branch in the same repo..